# How to Upload the Same File in Different Names for Each Users Using Foreach

Tags: php, loops, file, foreach, upload

other queries working through the foreach loop.but file upload for 1st index of array.this is not multiple file upload.i wanna upload same file in different names for each users.

```
    foreach($_POST['groupmem'] as $user){
    //Some Queries

    $filename2 = str_replace(" ", "_","{$user}.{$_FILES['proposal']['name']}");
    $destination2 = '../img/proposal/' . $filename2;
    $extension2 = pathinfo($filename2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file2 = $_FILES['proposal']['tmp_name'];
    $size2 = $_FILES['proposal']['size'];
    if (!in_array($extension2, ['zip', 'pdf', 'docx'])) {
        echo "You file extension must be .zip, .pdf or .docx";
    } elseif ($_FILES['proposal']['size'] > 200000000) { // file shouldn't be larger than 200Megabyte
        echo "File too large!";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($file2, $destination2)) {
            $sql = "UPDATE project SET proposal_name='$filename2' WHERE u_id='{$user}' ";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "File uploaded successfully";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Failed to upload file.";
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: you can not do move_uploaded_file inside the loop

Comment: you need to do only the first upload and then copy files with diferent filenames after this move_uploaded_file

Comment: @AntonioAbrantes Thanks dude for solution.it works.you save my time.Thanks.

Comment: Godd , dont forget to click on green flag to close question

Comment: Thanks for the knowing.. @Dharman how i jump through that kind of SQL injections except mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: Use placeholders and parameters. See for example here: https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement

Comment: Thank you for suggetions. ill be go through it. @Dharman

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can not do move_uploaded_file inside the loop

```
$user1 = $_POST['groupmem'][0];
$filename1 = str_replace(" ", "_","{$user1}.{$_FILES['proposal']['name']}");
$destination1 = '../img/proposal/' . $filename1;
$extension1 = pathinfo($filename1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file1 = $_FILES['proposal']['tmp_name'];
$size1 = $_FILES['proposal']['size'];
if (!in_array($extension1, ['zip', 'pdf', 'docx'])) {
    echo "You file extension must be .zip, .pdf or .docx";
} elseif ($_FILES['proposal']['size'] > 200000000) { // file shouldn't be larger than 200Megabyte
    echo "File too large!";
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($file1, $destination1)) {

    foreach($_POST['groupmem'] as $user){
        $filename2 = str_replace(" ", "_","{$user}.{$_FILES['proposal']['name']}");
        $destination2 = '../img/proposal/' . $filename2;
        if ($user <> $user1) {
            if (!copy($destination1, $destination2))  echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE project SET proposal_name='$filename2' WHERE u_id='{$user}' ";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "File uploaded successfully";
        }
    }

    } else {
        echo "Failed to upload file.";
    }

}
```